# How to delete the jump of anchors?

Tags: jquery, css, anchor

I have a menu (with ul and li) who call #anchors, thy are located just at the right of the menu, so I don't want to have a jump in the page for nothing (informations are already on the screen). I tried onclick event, it don't work (I have loaded Jquery on my page, so I don't know why it doesn't work. I have read dozen of pages for my question in this site but nothing helped me.

If anybody have an answer to avoid the jump of the anchors, it would be nice.

Comment: Some relevant code is more than welcome. It's necessary in order for us to help you. You can construct a test case in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to make things easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("a[href^='#']").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

This will capture the click event and prevent the default action which is jumping and navigating.
The selector is for elements that have links that start with "#" such as the anchors.

Comment: This code is useless. You'll never click on the anchor, but on the menu. [EDIT : I see you already changed it, better]

Comment: @user1478018 in order to get better answer, provide a jsfiddle or post the markup.

Comment: Thanks for the quicker answer ! But it don't work, I have placed
`<script> $("[href^='#']").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }); </script> `
before my menu, with Jquery loaded, and the jump is already effective (ie and firefox)... :/ any ideas ?

Comment: @user1478018. You need to put the code inside `$(function(){})` John, I would add `a` to your selector.

Comment: with `<script>
$(function(){
$("[href^='#']").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
});
})
</script>`, it seems to work : the anchors jumps are not effectives, the links are presents, but the informations don't appears :/ Thanks for your help :)